Cannot find module '@angular/core/testing' from ''__file_name"
I'm trying to configure Jest in my Angular version 14 project , I'm getting this error whenever I tried to run the Run test command
Here In Below I attached the error I'm getting


Test suite failed to run

Cannot find module '@angular/core/testing' from 'node_modules/@testing-library/angular/fesm2015/testing-library-angular.mjs'

Require stack:
  node_modules/@testing-library/angular/fesm2015/testing-library-angular.mjs
  src/app/tester.ts
  src/app/core/components/footer/footer.component.spec.ts

  at Resolver.resolveModule (node_modules/jest-resolve/build/resolver.js:324:11)
  at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/@testing-library/angular/fesm2015/testing-library-angular.mjs:4:31)


This is my setup.jest.ts file,


import "jest-preset-angular"



My jest.config.js


// jest.config.ts
const { pathsToModuleNameMapper } = require('ts-jest/utils')
const { compilerOptions } = require('./tsconfig.json')

// Sync object with async function
module.exports = {
  name: 'Streamhub Activate',
  displayName: {
    name: 'Streamhub Activate',
    color: 'blue',
  },
  verbose: true,
  preset: "jest-preset-angular",
  roots: ['<rootDir>/src/'],
  testMatch: ['**/+(*.)+(spec).+(ts|js)'],
  setupFilesAfterEnv: ["<rootDir>/src/setup.jest.ts"],
  "globalSetup": "jest-preset-angular/global-setup",
  collectCoverage: true,
  coverageReporters: ['html'],
  collectCoverageFrom: ["./src/**"],
  coverageDirectory: 'coverage/streamhub-syntese',
  coverageThreshold: {
    global: {
      lines: 50
    }
  },
  moduleNameMapper: pathsToModuleNameMapper(compilerOptions.paths || {}, {
    prefix: '<rootDir>/',
    "@app/*": "<rootDir>/src/app/$1",
    "@environments/*": "<rootDir>/src/environments/$1",
    "@shared/*": "<rootDir>/src/app/shared/$1",
    "@core/*": "<rootDir>/src/app/core/$1",
    "@activate/*": "<rootDir>/src/app/modules/activate/$1",
    "@analytics/*": "<rootDir>/src/app/modules/analytics/$1",
    "@admin/*": "<rootDir>/src/app/modules/admin/$1",
  }),
  testPathIgnorePatterns: [
    '<rootDir>/node_modules/',
    '<rootDir>/dist/',
    '<rootDir>/builds/',
    '<rootDir>/cypress/'
  ],
  transformIgnorePatterns: ['node_modules/(?!.*.mjs$|@datorama/akita)'],
  globals: {
    "ts-jest": {
      "stringifyContentPathRegex": "\\.html$"
    }
  }
};



This is my package.json


{
  "name": "project",
  "version": "2.32.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.json",
    "start:verbose": "ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.json --verbose",
    "build": "ng build",
    "watch:dev": "ng build --watch --configuration development",
    "watch:prod": "ng build --watch --configuration production",
    "test:watch": "jest --watch --all",
    "test:coverage": "jest --watch --all --coverage",
    "test": "jest",
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=16"
  },
  "private": true,
  "cypress-cucumber-preprocessor": {
    "step_definitions": "cypress/support/step_definitions/",
    "cucumberJson": {
      "generate": true,
      "outputFolder": "cypress/cucumber-json",
      "filePrefix": "",
      "fileSuffix": ".cucumber"
    }
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular-slider/ngx-slider": "^2.0.4",
    "@angular/animations": "^14.2.9",
    "@angular/cdk": "^14.2.6",
    "@angular/cli": "^14.2.8",
    "@angular/common": "^14.2.9",
    "@angular/compiler": "^14.2.9",
    "@angular/core": "^14.2.9",
    "@angular/flex-layout": "^14.0.0-beta.41",
    "@angular/forms": "^14.2.9",
    "@angular/localize": "^14.2.9",
    "@angular/material": "^14.2.6",
    "@angular/material-moment-adapter": "^14.2.6",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^14.2.9",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^14.2.9",
    "@angular/router": "^14.2.9",
    "@auth0/angular-jwt": "^5.1.0",
    "@datorama/akita": "^7.1.1",
    "@datorama/akita-ng-effects": "^1.0.6",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-pro": "^6.1.1",
    "@highcharts/map-collection": "^2.0.1",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^11.0.0",
    "@ng-select/ng-select": "^9.1.0",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "^14.0.0",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^7.0.0",
    "@popperjs/core": "^2.11.2",
    "@schematics/angular": "^13.2.0",
    "@swimlane/ngx-charts": "^20.1.0",
    "ag-grid-angular": "^27.1.1",
    "ag-grid-community": "^27.1.0",
    "array-uniq": "^3.0.0",
    "autoprefixer": "10.4.5",
    "bootstrap": "^4.6.0",
    "bootstrap-icons": "*",
    "core-js": "^3.20.3",
    "cypress-cucumber-attach-screenshots-to-failed-steps": "^1.0.0",
    "cypress-localstorage-commands": "^1.7.0",
    "cypress-tags": "^0.3.0",
    "cypress-visual-regression": "^1.7.0",
    "file-saver": "^2.0.5",
    "highcharts": "^9.3.2",
    "highcharts-angular": "^3.0.0",
    "iconv-cp932": "^1.1.0",
    "iconv-lite": "^0.6.3",
    "jest-createspyobj": "^2.0.0",
    "jquery": "^3.6.0",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
    "jszip": "^3.10.0",
    "mixpanel-browser": "^2.43.0",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "moment-duration-format": "^2.3.2",
    "moment-timezone": "^0.5.40",
    "multiple-cucumber-html-reporter": "^1.20.0",
    "ng-click-outside2": "^10.0.4",
    "ng-multiselect-dropdown": "^0.3.8",
    "ngx-color-picker": "^13.0.0",
    "ngx-infinite-scroll": "^14.0.0",
    "ngx-logger": "^5.0.7",
    "ngx-plyr": "^4.0.1",
    "ngx-youtube-player-14": "^7.1.16",
    "pako": "^2.0.4",
    "plyr": "^3.7.8",
    "popper.js": "^1.16.1",
    "rxjs": "~7.5.2",
    "tslib": "^2.3.1",
    "uuid": "^8.3.2",
    "xlsx": "^0.17.5",
    "xlsx-js-style": "^1.2.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^14.2.8",
    "@angular-devkit/core": "^14.2.8",
    "@angular-eslint/builder": "14.1.2",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin": "14.1.2",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin-template": "14.1.2",
    "@angular-eslint/schematics": "14.1.2",
    "@angular-eslint/template-parser": "14.1.2",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^14.2.9",
    "@angular/language-service": "^14.2.9",
    "@cypress/browserify-preprocessor": "^3.0.2",
    "@cypress/schematic": "^1.6.0",
    "@datorama/akita-ngdevtools": "^7.0.0",
    "@katoid/angular-grid-layout": "^2.0.0",
    "@testing-library/angular": "^11.0.2",
    "@testing-library/cypress": "^8.0.2",
    "@testing-library/dom": "^8.11.3",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.1",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.10.3",
    "@types/jest": "^27.4.0",
    "@types/jquery": "^3.5.13",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.178",
    "@types/mixpanel-browser": "^2.36.0",
    "@types/node": "^17.0.18",
    "@types/pako": "^1.0.3",
    "@types/youtube": "^0.0.47",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.36.2",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.36.2",
    "concurrently": "^7.0.0",
    "cypress": "^10.4.0",
    "cypress-cucumber-preprocessor": "^4.3.1",
    "del": "^6.0.0",
    "eslint": "^8.23.0",
    "eslint-plugin-cypress": "^2.12.1",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "2.25.4",
    "eslint-plugin-jest": "^26.1.1",
    "eslint-plugin-jsdoc": "37.7.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prefer-arrow": "1.2.3",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^4.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-testing-library": "^5.0.5",
    "jasmine-core": "~4.0.0",
    "jest": "^27.4.7",
    "jest-preset-angular": "^11.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.1.0",
    "lint-staged": "^12.3.2",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "ngx-translate-testing": "^6.0.1",
    "prettier": "2.5.1",
    "semver": "^7.3.5",
    "sonar-scanner": "^3.1.0",
    "typescript": "~4.8.4"
  },
  "overrides": {
    "autoprefixer": "10.4.5"
  }
}



I'm using angular 14 and the version of the jest is 27.4.7
Getting this error for a long , did anyone have any idea , please provide a solution for this.
